# Решение задачи из учебника Гэддиса Т. Кореектор предложений

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно решить задачку из книги Гэддиса. Т. "Начинаем программировать на Pyhton".
Условия задачи:
Напишите программу с функцией, принимающей в качестве аргумента строковое значение и возвращающей его копию, в котором первый символ каждого предложения написан в верхнем регистре. Например, если аргументом является "привет! меня зовут джо. а как твое имя?", то эта функция должна вернуть строковое значение 'Привет! Меня зовут Джо. А как твое имя?'. Программа должна предоставить пользователю возможность ввести строковое значение и затем передать его в функцию. Реузльтат должен быть выведен на экран.
Вот мой код:

```
def korr_pred(n: str):
    n = list(n) #делаем из строки список символов
    n[0] = n[0].upper() #делаем первую букву строки большой

    for i in range(len(n)): #пробегаемся по списку
            
        if n[i] == ' ' and n[i-1] in '.!?': # тут условие, если текущий символ пробел, а предыдущее '.!?'
            n[i+1] = n[i+1].upper() #то следующий символ делаем большим
        n = ''.join(n) #собираем все в строку
    print(n)
n = input()
korr_pred(n)
```

В принципе, с условием задачи я справился. Начало предложений у меня с большой буквы. Но вот как сделать с большой буквы имя???

Comment: В задаче не написано, что имена тоже должны быть с большой буквы. Или условия неполные, или в просто примере ошибка.

Comment: Да я тоже так подумал. Спасибо.